# My new Github Page is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: github, github-actions, project, profile, portfolio

I have been following Joshua Flukes video on how to make a portfolio with github pages but when i committed everything it doesn't show up. My github repo is:
Davecarranza.github.io

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-check your [GitHub Pages publication source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) and, depending on said source, make sure you have committed in the right folder *and pushed* in the right branch.

Only then would you see anything in your project GitHub page site.